# Messagebox does not get removed until Python launcher is updated

Tags: python, tkinter

Im running a Python program on Mac running macOS Mojave with version 3.5.0. I am trying to make a tkinter window appear after messagebox closes but it doesn't unless i update Python launcher by clicking on the icon in the dock, and there is no problems that are relatable with this one.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

players = 2
choices = []

# getting rid of dummy windows.
window = tk.Tk()
window.withdraw()

for i in range(players):
    player_id = i + 1
    result = messagebox.askyesno("Account Settings", "Player " + str(i + 1) + "," " would you like to sign in?")
    choices.append((player_id, result))

window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()
button = Button(window, text="Please click me", command=lambda: print("clicked!"))
button.pack()
window.mainloop()    

def get_choices():
    return choices
```

Any input from you would be appreciated.

Comment: I made an edit just now, but it is not exactly my window. My main setup for the window to appear after the messagebox closes is in a different file. I imported this class ( the code in this problem) in my main file so that code would run before my main class would.

Comment: Calling `Tk()` multiple times in a program leads to all sorts of problems.  You may have better luck by either reusing your original `window`, or using `Tk.Toplevel()` for the second window.